# estimate cost of equity (Re) / required rate of return using DCF

Tags: finance, capm, investing, wacc, dcf

I'd like to estimate Amazon's after-tax cost of equity (Re) using both the DCF and CAPM approaches. Tons of info and resources on how to estimate Re using CAPM, but DCF, I see no relevant resources. How exactly can I do this?

I have an idea, can anyone confirm: Instead of using future cash flow for period n, I use projected revenue %growth?

Comment: My objective is to find the rate of return that investors require to purchase equity in Amazon (Re), then to use that in combination with CAPM to find WAAC. The standard way to find cost of equity is CAPM, I'm also seeing another method called Dividend Capitalization Model--but that's not what I'm looking for. Does a DCF method to find after tax Cost of Equity (Re) actually exist?

Comment: The reason why I'm confused is because DCF tells me what my future cash value will be of a particular investment, or the share price in the case of a stock. It's a dollar amount. But I'm looking for an after tax rate of return. Perhaps my question should be, how do I go from the share price using DCF to a rate of return?

Comment: The WACC is the discount rate used in the DCF model, solve the WACC for the current Amazon valuation then remove the debt part of the WACC to solve for Re

Comment: Ok, so I have: Amazon WACC =  Re (E/Tot) + Rd (1-t) D/Tot
| =Re(796.1/820.8)+.034(1-.21)(24.7/820.8)
| =Re(.97)+.008
| Remember, Re is supposed to be (CAPM + DCF)/2
| Now how am I supposed to calculate WACC?

Comment: If you have the future cash flows (CFn) and the total market value of debt + equity (MTM), you can solve for WACC : MTM = CF1/(1+WACC)+CF2/(1+WACC)^2...+CFn/(1+WACC)^n

Comment: I'm confused. Here is what I know. Cost of equity (Re) using CAPM, Cost of Debt (Rd), Market value of Equity (E), Market Value of Debt (D), but I'm missing Cost of equity using DCF. Using the WACC formula above, that's the only piece I'm missing (I need to use the average cost of equity using CAPM and DCF. (CAPM +DCF)/2.

Comment: How do you do a DCF if you don't have an estimate of the cash flows ?

Comment: Good point. though I'm sure I could get those cash flow estimates online -- for how many periods is standard? So I uses MTM = CF1/(1+WACC)+CF2/(1+WACC)^2...+CFn/(1+WACC)^n  solves for WACC? That's my cost of equity?

Comment: I'm also seeing in other sources I could used the Dividend Discount Method 
Po = P1 / (1+ Re) ||
Re = P1/ P0 - 1 || Though this is not DCF, is it?

Comment: Amazon doesn't pay a dividend

Comment: I know. I set Div=0, and using DDM for one-year investor